# Cucumber Selenium Java Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, cucumber

I am new to cucumber and I have just created a features a folder with a cucumber file but when I start I get the message:
Step: Open chrome and start application does not have matching glue code

Here are some snippets to help you understand my setup:

[image: file setup]

[image: libraries]

[image: cucumber file]

Comment: You need to right equivalent Java code for each Given, When, Then step, follow this tutorial : http://toolsqa.com/cucumber/step-definition/

Comment: I just want to run the cucumber file first

Comment: I shouldn't get an error so early on?

Comment: Yes, because there's no functionality to your tests without glue code.Cucumber without any other programming language is nothing.

Comment: I followed a tutorial on youtube and he ran the cucumber file standalone: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vv7hHrVX_Zg&t=991s

Comment: Did you make a runner class that runs the .feature file? I can't see it in your project tree. Tutorial that You sent covers all the basic topics, so there should not be any issue if You will follow it correctly :)

Comment: what error do you get, when you click right click on cucumber feature file > Run As Cucumber Feature

Comment: I don't get anything just a complete blank

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a runner class in your project, most cases its would be located here: src/test/java/stepDefinitions. This is the "glue" that lets cucumber know what features files to execute.

Call the class RunCuketest

The class structure should look like this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "classpath:features",
        strict = false,
        glue = "stepDefinitions",
        format = { "pretty"},
        tags = { "~@Ignore" }
)

public class RunCukeTest {

}
```